# Output this sequence of numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

Your challenge is to write a program or function to output [this](https://pastebin.com/MX3Sjirk) sequence of numbers.

Output requirements:

- Must contain numbers specified above
- Must be in order as specified
- Numbers must be delimited by whitespace

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Ah, feck, I've figured out 2 formulas for this but it's too fiddly to write them up, test them & golf them down on my phone.

Comment: [OEIS Sequence](https://oeis.org/A001563)

Comment: [A033312](https://oeis.org/A033312)

Comment: Guessing how you've generated a sequence is a poor fit for code golf. Once one person has solved the "puzzle", everyone can copy the idea.

Comment: @xnor Alright, I'll add modified version

Comment: That edit makes it [tag:restricted-source] instead of [tag:code-golf]

Comment: You've just made the winning criterion the language used for a solution. That's not a winning criterion.

Comment: Is this meant to be a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity]? Or do you take the number of numbers to output as input / output forever / output the number at a specific index? In any case, the specification of the challenge shouldn't be hosted on an external site. You should place the rule used for generating the numbers into the question.

Comment: @ais523 I don't know if it was KC at the time you read it, but it was originally KC but I removed that because the output requirements imply that there can be multiple valid outputs; thus, I don't believe that makes it KC (so I removed that along with [tag:arithmetic]).

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 76 bytes

```python
from math import*
s=2**32-5
for i in range(6499):print((s-factorial(i+1))%s)
```

[A033312](https://oeis.org/A033312).

## Python, 84 bytes

```python
from math import*
k=s=2**32-6
for i in range(6499):s-=i*factorial(i);s%=k+1;print(s)
```

[A001563](https://oeis.org/A001563).

Comment: Do you really need `k=`? As far as I can tell, `k=s=...` and `s` never changes so why not remove the `k=` and make `%k` into `%s`?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks

Comment: You can save 1 cheap byte by not importing `*`; [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpLCoAgEADQvadwE6hhkFZg0GEkMgfywzibTm/01q@@FEu2vUOqBYknT5G1wyhljV5ZKMiBQ@bo832JbXFO7hUhkxBN/3kK/qSC4B8B4yzl0GTvHw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 148 bytes

```python
a=[1]
n=6499
N=2**32-5
exec("a+=[a[-1]*len(a)%N];"*n)
a=[i*a[i]for i in range(n)]
for i in range(1,n):a[i]=(a[i]+a[i-1])%N
print([N-i-1 for i in a])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxBCsIwEEX3c4pQEJLULNJqoUqukAsMsxgkakCmJXShp4/pxoWbt3j899fP9lxkrJUDegIJ02meIYbB2nFwZ0jvdNMd9wEZnSf7SqLZHCJdOysGWpUtY6b7UlRWWVRheSQthuBP@aOYyz4Nemff0A7bFawly6YxuibUr2IytX4B)

Surely this can be golfed.

Comment: Took you literally 10 minutes :)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I only checked the beginning and the end though.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 39 bytes

```
Ａ⁻Ｘ²¦³²¦⁵σＡ¹φＡ¹κＦ⁶⁴⁹⁹«⁺﹪⁻σφσ¶Ａ⁺κ¹κＡ×φκφ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9noWPGne/37Pj0KZDyw5tBpGPGreebwaKH9p5vg1Mndv1fg9QdNujxi2PGncC0aHVjxp3vd@5CqjzfPP5tvPNh7aBzdl1bhdE9cLD08@3ndt1vu3/fwA)

### Explanation

```
Ａ         σ                                    Assign to s
  ⁻Ｘ²¦³²¦⁵                                     2 ** 32 - 5
            Ａ¹φ                                Assign 1 to f (factorial)
                Ａ¹κ                            Assign 1 to k
                    Ｆ⁶⁴⁹⁹«                     For i from 0 to 6498
                           ⁺﹪⁻σφσ¶             (s - f) % s + "\n" (implicitly printed)
                                   Ａ⁺κ¹κ       k = k + 1
                                         Ａ×φκφ Assign f * k to f
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

```
žJ5-6499FDN>!-sDŠ%,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6D4vU10zE0tLNxc/O0XdYpejC1R1/v//mpevm5yYnJEKAA)

Only checked first and last numbers. If you run it TIO will probably take a while to print them all

---

Explanation

```
žJ5-                # (2 ** 32) - 5; call this x
    6499F           # for N in 0 .. 6498. Stack entering loop: [x]
         D          # duplicate. Stack: [x, x]
          N>        # N + 1. Stack: [x, x, N + 1]
            !       # factorial. Stack: [x, x, (N + 1)!]
             -      # subtract. Stack: [x, x - (N + 1)!]
              s     # swap. Stack: [x - (N + 1)!, x]
               D    # duplicate. Stack: [x - (N + 1)!, x, x]
                Š   # cycle last three items. Stack: [x, x - (N + 1)!, x]
                 %  # modulus. Stack [x, (x - (N + 1)!) % x)]
                  , # pop and print. Stack: [x]
```